# Scala macro that returns ClassTag of abstract type and abstract path-dependent type

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I've been trying to write a macro that generates class tags of abstract types.

I generalized the code provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/19502658/2859613:

```
object Macro {
  import scala.reflect.ClassTag
  import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

  def typeClassTag[A: c.WeakTypeTag]
    (c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[ClassTag[A]] = {
    import c.universe._

    val A = c.prefix.tree.tpe.member(weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol.name).typeSignature

    c.Expr(q"implicitly[ClassTag[$A]]").asInstanceOf[c.Expr[ClassTag[A]]]
  }
}
```

Testing with a type class which abstract type is not path dependent:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import Macro._

trait GatewayService {
  type Request
  type Response

  def requestTag : ClassTag[Request]  = macro typeClassTag[Request]
  def responseTag: ClassTag[Response] = macro typeClassTag[Response]
}

trait TransferRequest
trait TransferResponse

trait TransferService extends GatewayService {
  type Request  = TransferRequest
  type Response = TransferResponse
}

class TransferServiceImpl extends TransferService

"TransferServiceImpl  requestTag and responseTag" should {
  "equal ClassTag[TransferRequest] and ClassTag[TransferResponse] respectively" in {
    val transferService = new TransferServiceImpl

    transferService.requestTag  shouldEqual implicitly[ClassTag[TransferRequest]]
    transferService.responseTag shouldEqual implicitly[ClassTag[TransferResponse]]
  }
}
```

The code above compiles and the test is successful. The macro works as expected when the abstract type is not path dependent.

Now look at this type class trying to invoke this macro with an abstract type that is path-dependent:

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import Macro._

trait GatewayFrontend {
  type Service <: GatewayService  // GatewayService was defined in the code above

  def requestTag : ClassTag[Service#Request]  = macro typeClassTag[Service#Request]
  def responseTag: ClassTag[Service#Response] = macro typeClassTag[Service#Response]
}

trait TransferFrontend extends GatewayFrontend {
  type Service = TransferService  // TransferService was defined in the code above
}

class TransferFrontendImpl extends TransferFrontend

"TransferFrontendImpl requestTag and responseTag" should {
  "equal ClassTag[TransferRequest] and ClassTag[TransferResponse] respectively" in {
    val transferFrontend = new TransferFrontendImpl

    transferFrontend.requestTag  shouldEqual implicitly[ClassTag[TransferRequest]]
    transferFrontend.responseTag shouldEqual implicitly[ClassTag[TransferResponse]]
  }
}
```

The code doesn't even compile. I get:

```
[error] No ClassTag available for <notype>
[error]       transferFrontend.requestTag  shouldEqual implicitly[ClassTag[TransferRequest]]
[error]                        ^
[error]
[error] No ClassTag available for <notype>
[error]       transferFrontend.responseTag shouldEqual implicitly[ClassTag[TransferResponse]]
[error]                        ^
[error]
[error] two errors found
[error] (macro-utils/test:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

How can I change the macro implementation to also support this use case?

I think this would require some sort of recursion, but I'm still a scala macro newbie and I don't have any clue of how to use recursion with macros.

Is there any library out there that supports this out of the box?